# Can someone explain The Secret Agent's Blunder / Oshibka rezidenta?

Tags: plot-explanation, oshibka-rezidenta

I watched this Russian film, [*The Secret Agent's Blunder* (1968)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0314471/), with English subtitles, but I found it hard to distinguish between the different characters.  Thus, I still don't really understand what was going on.  I can't find much in the way of summaries, synopses, or explanations about it.

Does anyone have a good explanation for what went on, or maybe even an explanation of the characters?

Comment: The plot description in the [Russian Wikipedia article](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ошибка_резидента) seems adequate; anyone up to translating?  For identifying the characters, names and pictures can be found [here](http://www.kino-teatr.ru/kino/movie/sov/4948/titr/).

Comment: As it stands the question is quite broad, though. Explain what was going on, explain the characters. Maybe you could rephrase it to one or more specific questions about the plot or it's characters?

Comment: @ChristianRau understood.  I was looking for guidelines on specificity in the help section of this SE, but didn't find much of use (perhaps this is a discussion more suited to meta).  My dilemma is, if I didn't understand really what was going on or who was doing what, I can't really ask more specific questions.

Comment: @NickAldwin If it is really the whole movie you didn't understand it seems like you won't get around a second view, or a good plot summary. ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau Well, that's the thing.  I couldn't find a good plot summary (in English), and I feel a second viewing would be more helpful once I have read a summary.